# Класс в классе и доступ к переменной

Tags: c++

Вот есть такой простой условный класс:

```
class my_class
{
 
public:
 
 
    void my_func()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    }
 
 
private: //-------------------------------------->
 
    int my_int;
 
 
 
    class my_private_class
    {
 
    public:
 
        void my_func_private()
        {
            std::cout << my_int << std::endl;
        }
 
    };
 
};
```

Хотелось бы получить доступ к переменной my_int внутри созданного класса my_private_class, но VS2019 выдает ошибку:

> нестатическая ссылка на член должна указывается относительно заданного
> объекта

Подскажите, можно ли как то все таки получить доступ к my_int из класса my_private_class ?

Comment: А Вы понимаете разницу между классом и объектом? Если к переменной внутри класса, тогда добавьте static. Иначе нужен именно объект.

Comment: @KoVadim, если я правильно понимаю, если объявить внутри класса статическую переменную - то эта переменная будет общей для всех объектов класса, а мне нужно, что бы эта переменная была общей только для одного созданного объекта класса - внутри этого класса.

Comment: вот вот. поэтому, нужен экземпляр этого самого класса, что бы к нему обратиться. А если его нет, то и обратиться нельзя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Класс `my_private_class` - это тип данных, формально включённый в класс `my_class`, однако это всё равно другой класс. И, соответственно, для того, чтобы получить доступ к полю `my_int` класса `my_class` из функции-члена класса `my_class::my_private_class`, вы должны как-нибудь передать этой функции ссылку на конкретный экземпляр класса `my_class`. Например так:

```
class my_class
{
 
public:
 
 
    void my_func()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    }
 
 
private: //-------------------------------------->
 
    int my_int;
 
 
 
    class my_private_class
    {
 
    public:
 
        void my_func_private(my_class & MyCls) //передаём ссылку на объект типа my_class
        {
            std::cout << MyCls.my_int << std::endl;
        }
 
    };
 
};
```