# Как обратиться к элементу родителя вложенного класса

Tags: c++

У меня есть класс

```
class A
{

    private:
    int a;
    class B
    {
        public:
        int b; 
        int foo();
    }
}

int A::B::foo()
{
    this->b = //a;??? Как обратиться к этому полю?
}
```

Comment: Напрямую никак, надо вручную передать указатель на A в B и там использовать.

Comment: Был уже подобный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1392383/%d0%9a%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9

Comment: Не забыли `B b;` внутри `A`?

Comment: @LShadow77, вопрос был похожий, но все же разный...

Comment: Да, можно так определить A::B::foo, только это функция член вложенного класса, и она может обращаться к членам этого класса.  Обращаться к не статическому члену  объемлющего(*это не родитель класс*) класса, можно только через объект(указатель) этого класса:  Например return  b = A().a;